# Adding Action Bar to an android app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm using this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html to create  and add items to the action bar in my app. However the items aren't showing up. This is the menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_alert"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
      android:title="@string/action_alert"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

I already added the theme in the manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
```

And finally this is the onCreateOptionsMenu in the Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I know the Action Bar is working fine because I can hide it with this without problems

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try returning true on onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: the overflow menu does not appear on devices with a hardware settings button. is that your case ?

Comment: I'm using a device with a settings button yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with devices a hardware settings button your overflow button is moved to the settings button, there are two alternatives to get around this:

**xml:**

Instantiate your own overflow:

```
<item android:title=""
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/overflow">
  <menu>    
   <item android:id="@+id/action_alert"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
      android:title="@string/action_alert"
      android:showAsAction="never" />

   <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
  </menu>
</item>
```

**.java:**

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {   
       menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);   
       menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {   
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that there are no icons showing up, try changind android:showAsAction="..." to android:showAsAction="always".  This will explicitly show the icons.  This is not a good solution if you're supporting multiple screen resolutions though.

Answer (score 0):

## XML Namespace

Try a custom namespace like below in your `menu.xml` file. You can replace custom by whatever you like.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
```

And then use that namespace in your items (same xml file) instead of the android namespace

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_alert"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
  android:title="@string/action_alert"
  custom:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

## Complete (working) Example

A more complete example can be found at [this menu-drawer-compat-example on github](https://github.com/hanscappelle/menu-drawer-compat-example). Content of the menu xml file there is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:hcpl="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<!-- used custom ns hcpl to force display of action buttons -->

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_websearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/action_websearch"
    hcpl:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

*This is an example project for the Android compat Actionbar, keep that in mind if you compare your code.*